# Go fmt is running forever at Goland

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

I've installed the last version of Goland recently, but it's nevermind, because this bug is reproducible on 2020* versions too. I enabled two file watchers - gofmt and goimports as usual and it worked perfectly until today. I don't know what happened. I just see
`Running file watcher "go fmt"` or `Running file watcher "go imports"` at the bottom of the IDE and they run forever. Here the output of the IDE cmd:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2021-10-28 15:56:49,433 [   2519]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,441 [   2527]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,441 [   2527]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "NetBeans 6.5" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,441 [   2527]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,470 [   2556]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: HtmlTools] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,932 [   3018]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.github] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,956 [   3042]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: JavaScript] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,956 [   3042]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: JavaScript] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,984 [   3070]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: PythonCore] 
2021-10-28 15:56:49,985 [   3071]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "NetBeans 6.5" not found [Plugin: PythonCore] 
2021-10-28 15:56:53,197 [   6283]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for com.intellij.execution.configuration.EnvironmentVariablesData 

WARN - n.process.BaseOSProcessHandler - Process hasn't generated any output for a long time.
If it's a long-running mostly idle daemon process, consider overriding OSProcessHandler#readerOptions with 'BaseOutputReader.Options.forMostlySilentProcess()' to reduce CPU usage.
Command line: /usr/local/go/bin/gofmt 
java.lang.Throwable: Process creation:
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler.<init>(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:32)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.<init>(OSProcessHandler.java:49)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.CapturingProcessHandler.<init>(CapturingProcessHandler.java:24)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.CapturingAnsiEscapesAwareProcessHandler.<init>(CapturingAnsiEscapesAwareProcessHandler.java:30)
    at com.intellij.plugins.watcher.TaskRunnerImpl$1$1.run(TaskRunnerImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:962)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:472)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I event tried completely remove all files under `~/.config/JetBrains/GoLand*` also with no success. Tried to remove .idea folder under project with the same result.

Use Linux Mint 20.2.

Comment: Why do you want to use gofmt and goimports together? goimports bundles gofmt formatting rules, so you don't need to use both.

Comment: By the way, you can try out the [EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/) of GoLand where gofmt and imports optimization is enabled on save action without file watchers: https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2021/10/08/goland-2021-3-eap-3-gofmt-on-save-proxy-support-for-ssh-the-ability-to-split-the-run-window-and-database-improvements/#gofmt-on-save-enabled-by-default

Comment: Thank you so much @s0xzwasd. EAP version is working great.

Comment: I get the same problem on Goland 2022.1